# Download an image from my page to my folder and drag and drop this image in my input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that when I click on this image, the browser saves it automatically in my folder after I drag and drop this image from my folder to my input file. So how can I do that?

```
<img src="img.png" id="imgId" onclick="imgFun()" />
<input type="file" />
```

```js
function imgFun() {
  // download this photo in my folder Images
  // drag and drop this image automatically from my folder to my input
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to perform the save to local disk operation without user interaction, then it's not possible.